# How to stop Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer from auto-restarting?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a program, which needs to access some files used by Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer. The only way i found is to close Explorer and IE processes - but Proc.Kill() and RestartManager - RmShutdown() are only closing them for a split second - and then, they restart. I have found a workaround: I'm using cmd - taskkill /im - but this is really ugly. Any better way to close them?

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to access and what for?

Comment: You need to modify system files? So... writing a virus?

Comment: Take it easy @jb he is not writing a virus. He is just writing a backdoor.. trojan!!

Comment: Nope, not a virus :-) I'm deleting ATI's video driver leftovers - and for some reason both Explorer and IE are accessing it's files (HWA?). Thing is, even after i stop Aero service (UxSms) - explorer still have opened handles for some ATI's files.

Comment: Sounds like those drivers aren't really "leftovers", but instead are actually used by the OS.  Recommendation: completely uninstall the ATI drivers and switch to a generic driver.  THEN delete the remaining ATI directories.  Then REBOOT and check again.  The drivers could be listed in a driver catalog that's being loaded, so you might have to go through the registry to remove any lingering references, reboot, and see if anything else has a hold on them.  Driver manufacturers (especially ATI/nVidia) aren't exactly known for having the best install/uninstall features

Comment: They are leftovers - corresponding device drivers were deleted earlier, only some files (Actively used for Hardware Acceleration by IE and Explorer) and shared DLL's were left. The thing i'm trying to do is not to delete these files - i can always reboot into LiveCD and delete them, i'm looking for a way to end Explorer and/or Iexplore processes from .NET without them restarting - the only tool that can do that is cmd-taskkill. BTW, installing generic driver before reboot causes system to hang on boot.

Comment: It is certainly possible to close Explorer for an extended period, since I've seen installers do it.  Unfortunately I don't know how.  Next time it happens I'll try to remember to let you know which software it is, if it's open source you could look at what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL ExitExplorer()
{
    HWND hWndTray = FindWindow(_T("Shell_TrayWnd"), NULL);
    return PostMessage(hWndTray, 0x5B4, 0, 0);
}
```

That's the code to gracefully exit Explorer :)
Found it here, on StackOveflow.